# CSS: 1 box shown when there should be 2

Tags: css

```
<div></div><div></div>
<style>
  div {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

if i check the output log, it shows 1 red box, when i should be seeing 2

what do I do?

is it because I haven't specified any id's for the divs?

if it is, how do I write CSS that can cater for 65535 options (a 256^2 array)

Comment: Your `div` selector is missing a closing curly brace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is already rendered two red divs but these look stick together so it looks like showing only one div.

you can easily fix like it.

```
<div></div><div></div>
<style>
  div {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 2px;
  }
</style>
```

to make two div in the same row, just add this code in the style.
`display: inline-block;`

here is more about [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) and [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)css property.

Comment: that is gppd, but how do i make the boxes **next** to eachother, and not above one another

Comment: just add `display: inline-block;` in style tag

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
width:16px;
height:16px;
background-color:red;
border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div></div><div></div>
```

It's working. Where is the problem ? I placed some borders for you to see.

Comment: how can i get the boxes to be next to eachother, not above one another?